# How to draw a line on middle of the Image or Video in opencv java

Tags: java, opencv

I found a solution just would like to share with others

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);

int frame_width = (int)camera.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);           //for example 640
int frame_height = (int)camera.get(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);      //for example 480

Point middle_of_frame_left = new Point();
Point middle_of_frame_right = new Point();

middle_of_frame_left.x = 0;
middle_of_frame_left.y = frame_height/2;

//middle_of_frame_left coordinate will be point(0,240)

middle_of_frame_right.x = frame_width;
middle_of_frame_right.y = frame_height/2;

//middle_of_frame_right coordinate will be point(640,240)

while (true) {
    // If next video frame is available
    if (camera.read(frame)) {
         Imgproc.line(frame, middle_of_frame_left, middle_of_frame_right,new Scalar(0, 0, 255) , 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though your solution is ingenious, this is not the right way to post it. A better way would be you finding a questions with this topic and post your answer there.

Comment: Sorry, I have posted it for the first time